# Header não resulta

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, header

Boas Pessoal,

Eu tenho um ficheiro em php que é chamado de pois de preencher um form num ficheiro html. A função desse ficheiro php é adicionar dados na base de dados e depois de inserir tem o seguinte código:

```html
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
 echo "<script>
             alert('Inscrição realizada'); //alerta1
     </script>";
      header('Location: ../register.htm');
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>
             alert('Inscrição não realizada'); 
     </script>";
  header('Location: ../register.htm');
  }
```

Mas depois de se clicar no *submit* não mostra o alerta1 nem vai para a pagina que lhe estou a mandar ir. Alguém sabe como isto se resolve? E alguém sabe como voltar para a pagina do *form* mas deixar as caixas de texto em branco?

Comment: Como está a TAG `<form>` do seu HTML ?

Comment: Parece que a consulta está retornando um erro e caindo no else, comente a linha dos `header` para fazer o teste. No else adicione a linha `echo mysqli_error($conexao);`

Comment: Agora não tem erro nenhum simplesmente isto insere na base de dados, vai para a pagina e não me dá o alerta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, a função `header` do PHP só funciona quando a mesma é colocada antes de qualquer saída para o cliente.

Ou seja, códigos como esse abaixo resultarão em erro:

```
<?php

$meus_dados = [1, 2, 3];

foreach($meus_dados as $dado) {
    echo $dado; // saída de dados
}

header('Location: anterior.php'); // Isso resulta em erro pois já houve uma saída
```

Apesar de não ser uma boa prática, se o que você precisa é redirecionar depois do `alert`, você pode usar `document.location` do javascript.

```
  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      echo "<script>
             alert('Inscrição realizada'); //alerta1
             document.location.href = '../register.htm';
           </script>";

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Wallace estava mesmo desesperado pois não sabia que se podia fazer isso. E se houver outro método eu desconheço pois não sabia de outro método para alem de o header.